# how to install the last copied file on ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

how to install the last copied file on ubuntu

i have multiple builds on my linux box. The name is same but the build numbers are different.

eg:     build_all_123_bugfix.upgrade--------copied first

build_all_124_feature.upgrade

build_all_125_bugfix.upgrade-----------recently copied

I want to install the recently copied build on my linux box. 
when i am using the below command the first copied build was installed instead of latest.

chmod +x *.upgrade---------copied using this

echo 'xxxx' | sudo -S ./*.upgrade --------installed using this

Is there any command that can help me to install the last copied build file.

i tried using ls -lt to sort the files based on time but not sure how to pick the top most file and install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a little bash script. -nt means "newer than" and compares the files last modification times.

```
newest=
for file in *.upgrade; do
    [[ "$file" -nt "$newest" ]] && newest="$file"
done

echo "$newest"       # run your command with "$newest"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you made my day :-)